# How to parse the specific content in the HTML to my App

Tags: html, swift, swiftsoup

I'm trying to parse data from a website to my own application. I manage to get the html and print the html using AlamoFire but I don't know how am I going to get the specific data from that html file.

Here I get the HTML and I'm trying to get the exchange data

```
func scrapeExchangeRate() -> Void {
    Alamofire.request("https://yatirim.akbank.com/tr-tr/doviz/sayfalar/default.aspx").responseString {
        response in
        print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
        if let html = response.result.value {
            self.parseHTML(html: html)
        }
    }
}

func parseHTML(html: String) -> Void {
    print("\(html)")
}
```

The statement prints out the entire HTML file as expected but I'm trying to extract the data here from the var starts like this

var dovizHesaplama = '{"EUR":{"USD":{"ask":1.14065,"bid":1.14058,"time":"2019-01-16T22:21:45.3497922+03:00"},"GBP":{"ask":0.88690615037710907,"bid":0.88705864053507533,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"XAU":{"ask":0.00088175725295877431,"bid":0.00088189402550006575,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"AUD":{"ask":1.5884277955716475,"bid":1.5889941487879631,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"CAD":{"ask":1.51113312,"bid":1.510812268,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"CHF":{"ask":1.128901305,"bid":1.12860391,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"CNY":{"ask":7.7056610749999992,"bid":7.70233674,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"DKK":{"ask":7.4654401849999994,"bid":7.463613346,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"ETH":{"ask":0.0091456863373957659,"bid":0.0091480590311196659,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"NOK":{"ask":9.74137913,"bid":9.738043924,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"NZD":{"ask":1.680975905,"bid":1.68064463,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"RUB":{"ask":75.636729629999991,"bid":75.603231241999993,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"SAR":{"ask":4.2788062799999995,"bid":4.277859348,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"SEK":{"ask":10.261743659999999,"bid":10.25894681,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"},"TRL":{"ask":6.09837116,"bid":6.094803288,"time":"2019-01-16T22:06:44+03:00"}

and I'm interested in the USD exchange rates starting here:

I specifically want to extract data like some specific currencies exchange rate bid and ask prices vs the USD. How do I select those specific values?

```
"USD":{"ask":1.0101010101010102,"bid":1.0105092966855296,"time":"2019-01-16T21:05:25.7963428+03:00"},"GBP":{"ask":0.78619318968011376,"bid":0.78663342416746818,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"XAU":{"ask":0.00078045880988148267,"bid":0.00078094926132039845,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"AUD":{"ask":1.4070218834113528,"bid":1.4087680143392298,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"CAD":{"ask":1.3381818181818181,"bid":1.338419563459984,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"CNY":{"ask":6.8226262626262635,"bid":6.82407033144705,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"DKK":{"ask":6.6151515151515161,"bid":6.6170169765561839,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"ETH":{"ask":0.0080872779031305863,"bid":0.00809184254232487,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"NOK":{"ask":8.6312121212121227,"bid":8.6322756669361365,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"NZD":{"ask":1.4894949494949494,"bid":1.4896928051738076,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"RUB":{"ask":67.052121212121222,"bid":67.059013742926439,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"SAR":{"ask":3.7890909090909091,"bid":3.790016168148747,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"SEK":{"ask":9.0835353535353534,"bid":9.0852869846402591,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"TRL":{"ask":5.4033333333333342,"bid":5.4027890056588523,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"XAG":{"ask":0.064750064750064756,"bid":0.0649010466721599,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"XPD":{"ask":0.000743858997658927,"bid":0.0007465456764177438,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"},"XPT":{"ask":0.0012522016836102078,"bid":0.001253951426656652,"time":"2019-01-16T20:50:16+03:00"}}
```

Comment: What you posted in the end is JSON. Where did you get this?

Comment: it look like you are receiving a json file. JSON is key / value format so the most easier way to get what you want is to convert the JSON answer into an object todeal with it.

Comment: I would recommend stripping the HTLM tags using a regex and then use decoding to make it into JSON

Comment: I think I'm getting an HTML file not JSON. I really don't understand how do I regex that

Comment: I guess that you are getting HTML, with some JS code, and since the JSON "is JS", you can treat the dictionary as JSON and parse it. The question is how to find  `var dovizHesaplama = '...'` And that's the main issue. But It could be good to show: `print("\(html)")` (even truncated) to see where you need to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like gavsta707 commented you can look up the var in the HTML content using the regular expression `var dovizHesaplama = '(.+)'`.

Then decode the JSON using the `JSONDecoder`. Note that you will need to specify the date format which is `YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ`.

Some code that does this might look like

```
import Foundation

struct ExchangeRates: Codable {

    struct Rate: Codable {
        let ask: Double
        let bid: Double
        let time: Date
    }

    struct OtherRates: Codable {
        let EUR: Rate
        let GBP: Rate
        let XAU: Rate
        let AUD: Rate
        let CAD: Rate
        let CHF: Rate
        let CNY: Rate
        let DKK: Rate
        let ETH: Rate
        let NOK: Rate
        let NZD: Rate
        let RUB: Rate
        let SAR: Rate
        let SEK: Rate
        let TRL: Rate
        let XAG: Rate
        let XPD: Rate
        let XPT: Rate
    }

    let USD: OtherRates
}

let jsonPattern = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "var dovizHesaplama = '(.+)'")
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://yatirim.akbank.com/tr-tr/doviz/sayfalar/default.aspx")!)
if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as NSString? {
    if let match = jsonPattern.firstMatch(in: string as String, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length)) {
        let json = string.substring(with: match.range(at: 1))
        let rates = try decoder.decode(ExchangeRates.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
        print(rates)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change `OtherRates` to have one property: `let rates: [String: Rate]`.